# How do I pass parameter to a `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

When I'm getting a message from popup I want to execute a script, simply:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, response) {

      chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"});
});
```

My problem: `content.js` needs the data from `message`. How do I pass it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, response) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: paramName=paramValue},function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"});
    });
});
```

They both get injected into the same isolated world, so `content.js` can refer to the same variables.

Comment: Problem: message is undefined. why ??

Comment: Should be `{code: "paramName=paramValue"}`